Unable to expand Material-ui accordion one at a time
I'm working on a project, I have requirement to show accordion which should only expand one at a time.
Even my code is same as Material-ui offical website code it was still not working.
My data structure:
const investmentScreenData: [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "....",
    icon: "....",
    points: [
      '...',
      '...',
      '...',
    ]
  },
{...},
{...}
]

Investment.jsx (Parent component):
{investMentScreenData.map((item, index) => {
 return <InfoAccordion key={index} item={item} />;
})}

InfoAccordion.jsx:
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };


return (
   <StyledAccordion
       expanded={expanded === item.id}
       onChange={handleChange(item.id)}
    >
    <StyledAccordionSummery
            aria-controls='panel1d-content'
            id='panel1d-header'
          >
     <Typography
                component='p'
                variant='p'
                fontSize={{ xs: '19px', sm: '24px', md: '19px', lg: '24px' }}
                fontWeight={500}
                fontFamily={'inter'}
                color={'text.darkGreen'}
              >
                {item.title}
              </Typography>
</StyledAccordionSummery>

<StyledAccordionDetails>
 {item.points.map((point, index) => {
                  return (
                    <StyledListitem key={index} disableGutters disablePadding>
                       ...
                    </StyledListitem>
        )
  </StyledAccordionDetails>
        </StyledAccordion>

When user click on a accordion previous opened accordion should close and open current clicked accordion.

can you create a sandbox replicating the issue

Here is an example of an accordion I had to create a few months ago
I created my own Accordion component which takes as an argument defaultExpanded.
interface AccordionComponentProps {
    readonly summary: string;
    readonly summaryIcon?: React.ReactElement;
    readonly content?: React.ReactElement;
    readonly defaultExpanded?: boolean;
    readonly disabled?: boolean;
}

export function AccordionComponent({summary, summaryIcon, content, defaultExpanded = false, disabled = false}: AccordionComponentProps): React.ReactElement {
    let [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(defaultExpanded);
    let handleAccordionChange = (): void => setExpanded(!expanded);

    return (
        <Accordion className="accordion" onChange={disabled === false ? handleAccordionChange : () => false} defaultExpanded={defaultExpanded}>
            <AccordionSummary className="summary-wrapper">
                <Box className={`summary ${disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
                    <Box className="summary-icon">
                        {summaryIcon}
                    </Box>
                    {summary}
                </Box>
                <ArrowDropDownIcon className={`expand-icon ${expanded ? 'expanded' : ''} ${disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}`} />
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails className="content">
                <Box>
                    {content}
                </Box>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    );
}

To close the last one when clicking on the next one I created a toggle function which switches the state of the default expanded and therefore closing the old only opening the next one. I created a code pen to better demonstrate it.
Code Pen


<!-- HTML -->
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
  .summary-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }
  
  .content {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
  }
</style>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState } = React; function Accordion({ title, content, isOpen, onClick }) { return (
  <div>
    <div className="summary-wrapper" onClick={onClick}>
      {title}
    </div>
    {isOpen &&
    <div className="content">{content}</div>}
  </div>
  ); } function App() { const [openAccordion, setOpenAccordion] = useState('login'); const toggleAccordion = (accordion) => { setOpenAccordion((prevAccordion) => (prevAccordion === accordion ? '' : accordion)); }; return (
  <div>
    <Accordion title="Login Information" content="Content for Login Information" isOpen={openAccordion==='login' } onClick={()=> toggleAccordion('login')} />
      <Accordion title="Property Information" content="Content for Property Information" isOpen={openAccordion==='property' } onClick={()=> toggleAccordion('property')} />
  </div>
  ); } ReactDOM.render(

  <App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>



